# Would there be problem disabling mei_me?

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I got this kernel message:

```
[ 5558.212276] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: FW not ready: resetting.
[ 5558.212315] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = ENABLED fw status = 90100055 340D0006 00000020 00000004 00000000 00000000
[ 5561.035517] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[ 5589.102169] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: FW not ready: resetting.
[ 5589.102228] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: unexpected reset: dev_state = ENABLED fw status = 90202052 340D0006 00000020 00000004 00000000 00000000
[ 5590.492489] mei 0000:00:16.0-55213584-9a29-4916-badf-0fb7ed682aeb: Could not read FW version
[ 5590.492497] mei 0000:00:16.0-55213584-9a29-4916-badf-0fb7ed682aeb: FW version command failed -5
```

Solution from other forum said that I should blacklist `mei_me` and `rmmod` it

```
sudo rmmod mei_me mei
[sudo] password for asd: 
rmmod: ERROR: Module mei is in use by: mei_hdcp
```

I have blacklisted it but haven't restarted, it seems `mei` used by `mei_hdcp`, would there be problem doing this after restarting?

Comment: I'd try the other way around: don't blacklist it, only `rmmod` mei_hdcp,  mei_me and mei. If your system stops working, you can reboot. If nothing happens, you can blacklist it.

Comment: ah it seems fine `rmmod: ERROR: Module mei_me is not currently loaded`